# If you discover a fact after the fact, how do you Datomic?

Tags: datomic

My understanding of EAVT is that T has to be when the fact is inserted into Datomic. Often in my work facts can be inserted into the system months after they occurred. Clearly I can add an "at" attribute to my schema, but this seems to defeat much of the value of Datomic. Are there patterns or techniques for conveniently handling this temporal disconnect?

The main problem I want to avoid is:

```
t=1: I receive a fact that at t=0 x=5
t=3: I receive a fact that at t=2 x=6
t=5: I receive a fact that at t=4 x=7
```

What was x @t=2.5?

To answer this question I think I have to query the entire history of x, and traverse a custom at field. Or do some sort of binary asof search. Neither seems very appealing.

Comment: The way you phrase the question in your update seems to conflate system time (`t` value) and event time. Is it more accurate to say `t=1: I receive a fact that at '2016-09-26T00:00:00Z' x=5`? In which case, the question would be "What was x at 2016-09-27:00:00:00Z?".

Comment: Would it be accurate to say your question is more about efficient access of historical attributes than where to store datetimes? I think I see what you're getting after. If the system time and event time are the same, you can use `as-of` to directly access the appropriate db. Otherwise, you'd have to look around for the appropriate db. Querying history has never been particularly slow for my use cases. Will these attributes have a lot of history?

Comment: Yes, that is the conundrum. :) In the particular case I have in mind attributes tend to change every 2 days, with history of up to 2 years. In an SQL database I would probably have a record for every change indexed by the event time, which should allow me to find the active record at that time efficiently. But I can't think of a way to do that in Datomic, except for a full history scan. Full history scan may be fine, but I'm interested if there is a better pattern for dealing with this conundrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, the `:db/txInstant` is a record of when a fact became known to the system. If the fact that became known was "when some event happened," I see no problem with adding an attribute for that knowledge, e.g. `:person/birthday` or `:historical-event/date-time`.

The only time I avoid adding date attributes is when "when this became known to the system" and "when this occurred" are the same *by definition*. For example, "when did the user create this todo item" *can be defined as* the `:db/txInstant` for when the todo item entered the database.

Comment: In my case the fact becomes known later. I've added a more concrete case of why the "at" approach doesn't feel right. Perhaps I'm just missing the correct way to query for a point in time when ingestion necessarily occurs after the fact (this occurs because of 3rd party data providers).

Answer (score 0):

Tim Pote is correct. The distinction between domain time (when something happened in the 'real world') and system time (when Datomic found out about it) is an important one, and modeling domain time explicitly is definitely a good approach when it may diverge from the system time.

Comment: My question is about efficiently finding the value of a fact at a particular time when this is done. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: All Datomic databases, including asof databases, provide multiple spanning indexes. Query against asof DBs will use the indexes to resolve the query efficiently.

Comment: Hi Marshall; thanks - I appreciate the input. I do not see how having a fast `asof` query helps in my scenario. To reiterate, I'm searching for a fact whose time is defined by domain time, so I must check the `value`. But for any given db there is only 1 value. So the only query I can think of is "give me all historical values between the timeframe I think the fact could have been ingested". The problem with that being the timeframe can be large in the scenario I'm facing.